# Clean URL username redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want `www.example.com/myusername/` to `www.example.com/profile.php?username=myusername`.

Using this code

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I am able to redirect  `www.example.com/profile/myusername/` to `www.example.com/profile.php?username=myusername` but how do I do it without including **/profile/**.

This is my directory index `DirectoryIndex home.php`

*Which I can always change*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: wait what ? this is so simple!  `-d` `-f`  are not even needed! Wow

Comment: Yes i know mean i have those, but they arent needed as per my problem. Its weird last time i tried it didnt work . Well thanks anyway